# Why I'm receiving emails from complaints@email-abuse.amazonses.com massively?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gmail, amazon-ses, google-workspace, email-spam

We have a service responsible for sending emails using AWS SES. This is working pretty well since we deployed it. But one strange thing start to happen a day ago (April 22, 2020). We have change nothing from our side and start to receives a lot of emails from Amazon SES:

[image]
[image]

What we already know:

- As it is happening with almost all emails we sent, not all users all
  are clicking in the "unsubscribe" link
- The users are receiving the emails, once we know they are clicking in
  the links inside of the emails
- The emails we sent two days ago are exactly the same emails we are sending today. Both content and configuration

If anyone have past for this kind of problem, any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

I haven't encountered the report abuse but have encountered the related bounce email issue several times.  Not much is useful from FAQ (https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/) but it does mention the reputation dashboard which you should be following to see if you are on the road to recovery.

Your tasks include:
**1) Investigating if you send an email that could be considered abuse/spam under local laws of the receiver**
At a minimum, you need to make sure you are offering the capability to unsubscribe and actually unsubscribe users in timely fashion.  But also review content with an eye on local laws.

**2) Ensure that users who do not want to receive email from you are removed.**
This should be part of above.

**3) Build up your reputation by increasing the percentage of valid emails.**
This has been an issue for us in systems that send a small amount of email...it takes time to build up from a dip.

**Remember** - AWS wants to ensure it's multi-tenant mail servers remain whitelisted and that other AWS customers aren't impacted by any one potential bad actor.